# Pre-build web site locally using Stasis during Capistrano deploy

Tags: git, capistrano

I'm trying to use Capistrano to deploy a static web site built with [Stasis](http://stasis.me). The code to build the site is kept in a Git repository, and I would like to keep the build products (i.e., the finished product of the site) out of the repository to minimize code smells.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to install the necessary libraries to build the site on the remote server, so I need to pre-build it as part of a Capistrano deploy using the local [copy strategy](http://bu.chsta.be/blog/2013-02-24/capistrano-deployment-strategies-deploy-via-a-copy/). I'm having trouble figuring out where to put the command to run `stasis` so that it comes after Capistrano checks out the repository from Git but before packaging and pushing everything to the remote server.

I don't think I can use Capistrano hooks because the build would need to occur inside the `deploy:update_code` task. I don't think I can use a Git post-checkout hook either because Capistrano checks out to a different location each time it does a deployment and Git hooks aren't cloned with the repository.

**config/deploy.rb**

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, "/directory/on/remote/server"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:build_script` parameter to do this.

```
set :build_script, "stasis"
```

This will run on the local copy before transferring it to the target. Most of the documentation for this is in the [Capistrano Source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb) as inline comments.